# Yoast setup for Robots is weird, <meta name="robots" content="index,follow, noindex" /> How do we remove the noindex part?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

On one of our sites, we have the Yoast plugin turned on.

However, on it's content tag is the weirdest thing. We see 3 values: `index,follow, noindex`

How do we exactly remove the `noindex` value? we tried looking at header.php as well as functions.php to no avail.

We also looked at the Yoast plugin, but there was no point there as to which we can edit the `content`

Comment: Did you try contacting Yoast plugin support? They are in the best position to know where this could be coming from.

Comment: Also, did you rule out the other plugins you are using? One of them might be updating this info.

Comment: Hi @FluffyKitten unfortunately not sure if they would answer me as I am not paying for Premium support.. but I will open a ticket.

Additional info as well, we checked `Settings`->`Reading` and found that `discourage robots` setting was unchecked... at the end of our wits here...

Comment: The support forum on the wordpress.org  plugin page is for all support, not just premium. If Yoast themselves don't answer, there are volunteers just like here that answer posts too, and you are more likely to find someone with Yoast expertise there. However its more likely being caused by something else - have you ruled out the other plugins i.e. turn them off one by one to see if it has any effect on the problem? Also, check if its your theme by enabling one of the default themes e.g. twentytwenty.

Comment: @FluffyKitten as an additional info, we updated to Version 14.1. a few weeks back. I see a wizard/walkthrough availabe. Could finishing that potentially remvoe this problem?

Comment: It's worth a try. If the issue was caused by the upgrade then its likely to have affected other users, and the support page on wordpress.org is where they'll all go for help, so it's definitely the place to start :) Don't forget to rule out your theme & plugins too - that will be the first question you'll be asked!

Answer (score 0):

Can override in functions.php globally or only for specific post type

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_robots', 'yoast_seo_robots_remove_single' );
/**
 * Set certain posts to noindex nofollow
 */
function yoast_seo_robots_remove_single( $robots ) {
    $postType = get_post_type();
    if ( is_single() && ($postType === "custom_event_name")) { 
     return 'noindex,nofollow'; 
    } 
    else {
     return 'index,follow';//to everything else, originally $robots value
    }
}
```